# how to apply formatting to specific value in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column of values that are all supposed to be in dollars. The first value is a number and I want to convert it to dollars to match the other values. What is the quickest way to apply formatting to a single row? I am hoping to get $247,000 in row [0].

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images. Post everything as text. Also, please post your expected output based on sample input for better clarity.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the easiest way to add dollar symbol (or any string) in every rows of the column.

```
dataframe[0] = '$'+dataframe[0].astype(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. use `iloc[0]` to find the first element in the column
2. format `f'{x:,}'` will give a number's thousand separate symbol, e.g. `f'{1000:,}'` give `'1,000'`

```
obj.iloc[0] = f'${obj.iloc[0]:,}'
```

Comment: While the code may be a valid answer, adding some explanation would make it more useful to OP and future readers